# Issue when trying to filter array in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

```js
data() {
    return {
      searchString: '',
      sortKey: 'name',
      checked: false,
      Item,
      items: [{
        price: '1',
        name: 'mm'
      }, ],

      computed: {
        computedItems() {
          return this.items.map((item, index) => {
            item.key = `item_${index}`
            return item
          })
        },
        index: function() {
          let searchString = this.searchString
          let itemsClone = [...this.items] // Change added
          const sortedArray = itemsClone.sort((a, b) => {
            if (a[this.sortKey] < b[this.sortKey]) return -1
            if (a[this.sortKey] > b[this.sortKey]) return 1
            return 0
          })
          if (!searchString) {
            return sortedArray
          } else {
            searchString = searchString.trim().toLowerCase()
            const search_array = sortedArray.filter((items) => {
              if (items.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1) {
                return items
              }
            })
            return search_array
          }
        }
      }
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
      <input
        type="text"
        v-model="searchString"
        placeholder="search items from here"
      />
      <br />

      <virtual-list
        class="list"
        style="height: 360px; overflow-y: auto"
        data-key="key"
        :keeps="20"
        :data-sources="computedItems"
        :data-component="Item"
      />
      <hr />
    </div>
```

Issue when trying to filter array in Vuejs?

I am able to render list of items, but issue is unable to filter the array file. I have taken v-model inside of my input search field, and then writing computed property to it, But still i am getting error

Can i use v-model inside of my search input and filter the data???

Comment: It seems like `computed` is part of the object returned from the data() function. You should place is so that the computed property is part of the Vue component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/live-demo-virtual-list-forked-hwq38?file=/src/App.vue) with code to filter items based on inputs.

```
computedItems() {
  let initItems = this.items.map((item, index) => {
    item.key = `item_${index}`
    return item
  })

  return initItems.filter((item) => item.name.includes(this.filterValue))
},
```

Comment: Thanks.it's working

Answer (score 1):

#### Check your `.filter()` function

Check the "Problems" tab to the right of the console at the bottom right:

- `Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function. (array-callback-return)`

The implementation looks like this:

```js
const search_array = sortedArray.filter((items) => {
  if (items.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1) {
    return items
  }
})
```

So the filter function would work like this:

```js
const search_array = sortedArray.filter((item) => {
  return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1;
});
```

You are supposed to return `true` if the item should be kept, not the item itself.
JavaScript will assume `items` is a true-ish value and that is valid code. It is just an eslint warning, but an important warning here.

See documentation of `.filter()`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

#### Make your search work

You simply forgot to use the correct search value variable.
You named it `filterValue` in data, but `index` uses `this.searchString`.
So fixing this in the first line of `index()`:

```js
let searchString = this.filterValue
```

If you output `{{ index }}` in your template, you can see your filtered array in real time while typing.